# mysql group by show count 0 not sure if I can left join here

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this query and I want to return a row when the count is 0

```
SELECT count(day) as count, day
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `day`
```

Other stackoverflow answers say that I need to do a left join.
But I don't know how to do it in this scenario.

Comment: Why do you think you need to join? That looks fine! Run it, see what happens. EDIT: Oop, wait up, you only want to select the days where they don't appear in the table..?

Comment: I ran it but it doesn't return rows that have count 0

Comment: you need another table that has days in it. of course those have counts!

Comment: Where is the full set of rows to compare against? I think I now understand what you're trying to do. You have a table with days, and another table with the full set of days, and you want to show the list of days in one table (the complete set) that don't appear in the other? Is that correct? Then we will need a join.

Comment: @drew Pierce so if I just create another table and log inside it the same value for days, it would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table theDays
(   aDay varchar(20) not null
);

create table sales
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    aDay varchar(20) not null,
    prodId int not null,
    qty int not null
);

insert theDays values ('sunday'),('monday'),('tuesday'),('wednesday'),('thursday'),('friday'),('saturday');
insert sales(aDay,prodId,qty) values ('tuesday',101,4),('thursday',107,2);

select d.aDay
from theDays d
left outer join sales s
on d.aDay=s.aDay
where s.aDay is null

+-----------+
| aDay      |
+-----------+
| sunday    |
| monday    |
| wednesday |
| friday    |
| saturday  |
+-----------+
```

Comment: i realize this is a crummy example, choose whatever datatype you want. obviously day would be much better as a datatype `date` but you get the idea. somepeople have a utility table hanging out there with every date back 10 years, forward 10 years, just to do outer joins with